# Having Hard time with Runtime Complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm very very fresh to C# and programming overall (especially on algorithms).

I'm trying to learn the basic of algorithms and I really do not know to answer on certain questions:
[image]

I need to answer on each, what is the complexity.
Now I've answered the following:

**1)** O(2N)
**2)** O(1)? I guessed here and couldn't tell why O(1)
**3)** Couldn't tell
**4)** Couldn't tell
**5)** O(N^2) ? took a nice guess here.
I would really really really appreciate any help followed by explanation.

Comment: Try following the loop code in each case. How many times does "Basic Operation" get executed, as a function of *n*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This loop counts up from 0 to *n*–1, which is *n* iterations. Each iteration performs 2 basic operations. Hence a total of 2*n* basic operations are performed. *O*(2*n*) is the same as *O*(*n*) because we disregard constants.
2. This loop counts down from 100 to 1, which is 99 iterations. Each iteration performs 2 basic operations. Hence a total of 198 basic operations are performed. *O*(198) is the same as *O*(1) because we disregard constants.
3. The outer loop counts from 100 to floor(*n*/2)–1. If *n*<200, then no iterations are executed and the run time is *O*(1) for the loop initialization and test. Otherwise *n*≥200, then approximately (*n*/2)–100 iterations are executed. The inner loop executes *n* times, performing 1 basic operation each time. Hence a total of about ((*n*/2)–100)×n×1 = (*n*<sup>2</sup>)/2 – 100n basic operations are executed, which is *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).
4. The first loop executes *n* basic operations in total. The second and third loops combined execute *n*<sup>2</sup> basic operations in total. Thus a total of *n* + *n*<sup>2</sup> basic operations are executed. The *n*<sup>2</sup> term has a higher power than the *n* term, so the overall complexity is simply *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).
5. The outer loop executes *n* times. The inner loop executes *n*<sup>2</sup> times per outer loop iteration. Hence in total, *n*<sup>3</sup> basic operations are executed, which is *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: I Really appreciate the long explanation! I actually solved 4 and 5 alone now that I've grasped the concept. Have a good one!